# Hide one div on ng-click within ng-repeat when another div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
<li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
    <h4><a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
     <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="showDetails">
        <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
     </div>
</li>
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/

At a time i want only current procedure that is clicked to be shown. If i click on another procedure then the previous procedure should be hidden.

Pls help out to solve.

Comment: What's wrong ? The fiddle does exactly what you say

Comment: Procedure 1 : Clicked ( Displays the description)    Procedure 2: Clicked (Displays the description, but procedure 1 description is still shown)  I want to like this,                                                                                                                                         Procedure 1 : Clicked (Should display description) Procedure 2: Clicked (Should display description of procedure 2 and should hide the description of procedure 1)

Comment: Just updated you jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1282/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

### html

```
<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="displayDescription($index)">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="procedure.isShow">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### js

```
function sample ($scope) 
{    
    $scope.procedures = [
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 1',
            discharged: 23,
            isShow: false
        },
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 2',
            discharged: 2,
            isShow: false
        },
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 3',
            discharged: 356,
            isShow: false
        }
    ];

    $scope.displayDescription=function(index)
    {
       $scope.procedures[index].isShow = true;

       for(var i=0;i<$scope.procedures.length;i++)
       {
          if(i!=index)
          {
            $scope.procedures[i].isShow = false;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can manipulate it with an added attribute e.g. visible to object

```
function sample ($scope) {

    $scope.procedures = [
        {
                id:1,
            definition: 'Procedure 1',
            discharged: 23,
            visible:false
        },
        {
                id:2,
            definition: 'Procedure 2',
            discharged: 2,
            visible:false
        },
        {
                id:3,
            definition: 'Procedure 3',
            discharged: 356,
            visible:false
        }
    ];

  $scope.manipulateVisibility = function(obj){
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.procedures.length; i++){
                if(obj==$scope.procedures[i]){
                    $scope.procedures[i].visible=true;
            }else{
                    $scope.procedures[i].visible=false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

working sample can be found at 
http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1281/

Comment: @LavanyaD in above example added field `id` is not necessary there, but it makes sure every object is unique in some way rather than being dependent on just names!